# Camera2 API crashing on 4.3 device

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, samsung-mobile

My app is receiving the following crash on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.3:

```
06-15 10:46:45.260 6649-6649/com.company.appname E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager', referenced from method com.company.appname.fragments.menu.MyFragment.flashLightOff
06-15 10:46:45.260 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 176 (Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraManager;) in Lcom/company/appname/fragments/menu/MyFragment;
06-15 10:46:45.260 6649-6649/com.company.appname D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0010
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve exception class 175 (Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraAccessException;)
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x1e
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/company/appname/fragments/menu/MyFragment;.flashLightOff (Landroid/view/View;)V
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x001e
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/company/appname/fragments/menu/MyFragment;.flashLightOff (Landroid/view/View;)V
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/company/appname/fragments/menu/MyFragment;
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-15 10:46:45.265 6649-6649/com.company.appname W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d56700)
06-15 10:46:46.045 6649-6649/com.company.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.VerifyError: com/company/appname/fragments/menu/MyFragment
                                                                                at com.company.appname.adapters.NavigationCollectionPagerAdapter.<init>(NavigationCollectionPagerAdapter.java:16)
                                                                                at com.company.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle uses these settings which I believe to be relevent:

```
  android {
         compileSdkVersion 23
         buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
          ...
     }

     ...
     dependencies {
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
         ...
     }
```

The manifest has the following:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and the culprit method is like so:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
...
public void flashLightOff(View view) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        try {
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) BDApplication.getGlobalContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            manager.setTorchMode(manager.getCameraIdList()[0], false);
        } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
            Logger.logError(cae.getMessage());
            cae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {

        try {
            if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.logError("Error turning off Flashlight", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This crash occurs when the app launches, specifically when the fragment is created.  This method is never called, from everything I can read the simple (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) guard should protect against this type of crash, however it does not seem to on some devices.

I have a limited number of test devices available, and only on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with 4.3 does this crash occur.  Other devices include a Note 2 with 4.4, varioues devices with 5, and 6, all which work as expected.

I'm at a loss as to where my issue lies, can someone point me in the right direction?

edit:  The stack trace does not truely reflect what I believe to be the culprit, the stack trace is when the fragment containing the "Camera2" clssses are created, however they are never called at this point.  The crash, as I believe it, is due to the dalvik VFY unable to resolve errors.

Comment: "and the culprit method is like so" -- that does not appear to be the code referenced in your stack trace. You are crashing in an initializer or constructor in `NavigationCollectionPagerAdapter` (specifically, whatever line 16 is).

Comment: Sorry about that, I had the "on" method, should have been the off.  Both exhibit the same behaviour however.  I have edited to include the referenced method.  The crash is actually coming from the dalvik VFY, rejecting the cast, the stack trace is a side effect of that crash, I thought it worthwhile to include.  Line 16 is creating the class in which the camera is contained.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by pulling the camera2 class refrences into a new class, and then guarding them as I did above.

```
public void flashLightOff(View view) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        FlashLightManager.flashlightOff();
    }else
    {
        try {
            if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.logError("Error turning off Flashlight", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I will likely move both into the "FlashLightManager" after some testing.